# Indexeddb implicit key type conversion

Tags: javascript, html, dart, protocol-buffers, indexeddb

I'm using Dart to store a Protobuf `GeneratedMessage` into Indexeddb on Dartium. But somewhere (inside Indexeddb?) the types of my `Map` keys are changed and I'd like to know why.

Adding to the database works, if you don't try to add Dart objects:

```
...
var database = ...
var transaction = database.transaction('myStore', 'readwrite');
var store = transaction.objectStore('myStore');
var jsonMap = myMessage.writeToJsonMap();
store.put(jsonMap, myKey)
    .then((key) => print("Key added to database ${key}"))
    .catchError((e) => print(e));
...
```

The `jsonMap` is of type `Map<String,dynamic>`. The int keys from the `GenericMessage`s are converted to `String`.
When reading the result back this is different:

```
...
store.getObject(myKey).then((object) {
    var message = new MyGeneratedMessage();
    message.mergeFromJsonMap(object);
...
```

Here object is still a Map but the keys are `int` which terribly fails in `mergeFromJsonMap`.

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'source'.
```

To circumvent this problem I'm currently doing a copy of the result into a new map while changing the key type.

```
...
var clonedMap = new Map<String, dynamic>();
object.forEach((key, value) {
    clonedMap[key.toString()] = value;
});
...
```

My question is this: Why does this happen? Is this an expected behavior? Is this the result of `JavaScripts` poor type system? Is this a known bug?
Is this an attempt to optimize the used storage in Indexeddb that should be working in JavaScript according to [ECMA-262 § 11.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)? If all object keys are implicitly converted to `String` shouldn't this happen to all results of Indexeddb?

Comment: Sounds weird. Did you have a look how it's done in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/lawndart ?

Comment: The interface of lawndart does not allow to insert objects. It has `Future save(String obj, String key)`.

Comment: Looks similar to http://dartbug.com/16461 and http://dartbug.com/22991

Comment: These bugs are related but different. The first one is triggered after dart2js. The second one is strange. 1. The (current) lawndart api does not allow this 2. If keys are returned as String my bug should not occur ;-) So I've submitted a new bug report https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23366

Comment: Is it only in Dartium, or does it also affect dart2js?

Comment: @AlanKnight I compiled my code and tested it against Chrome (42.0.2311.135 (64-bit): The dart2js version does not throw an exception and is not affected.